# I'm using AlertDialog.adaptive, but I can't change the background color of the dialog displayed on IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, material-ui, flutter-cupertino

I am using AlertDialog.adaptive, but in Android, if you specify the background color with `backgroundColor`, it will be reflected in the background color.

However, on IOS, even if you specify a color with `backgroundColor`, it is not reflected.
How can I specify the background color of `AlertDialog.adaptive` even on IOS?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to do that with `AlertDialog.adaptive`. In iOS this will create a [CupertinoAlertDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoAlertDialog-class.html) which won't use the provided background colour. You can read the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog/AlertDialog.adaptive.html) to know more details about this behaviour.

The possible solutions are either you create your own widget which will mimic the dialog behaviour or use any third-party libraries (like [material_dialogs](https://pub.dev/packages/material_dialogs))